# I Need help converting curl to C#

Tags: curl

```
 // $ curl -u API_KEY: \
 //   -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \ -d '{"status":"Ready"}' \ SomeUrl {"ok":true}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest looking into making a C# web-client (There's a lot of easy to find example programs that work with a simple google search).

Do some research on the html protocol and tcp/ip protocols if you don't understand the example programs.

For parsing JSON, there's a lot of handy open source Libraries to help with that.

Comment: There is nothing to parse, that is all the data I need to send

Comment: I am not familiar with the curl sintax

Comment: Oh okie that makes life easy. Just place the string in the data section of the http request and you should be golden. Hopefully you were able to find a usable example program on google?